# Is it wrong to write HIGH to a pin used as an open collector?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, pullup

I'm a software engineer playing with PICs and have an old PS/2 mouse that I am using (successfully), which has CLK and DATA connections as open collectors.

So I have configured the internal pullups on the relevant PIC pins and am setting TRIS to 1 to let the lines go high and setting TRIS to 0 and writing 0 to the relevant PORT bit to force it low.

However, I've seen several similar PIC-to-PS/2 mouse implementations that, when writing to the mouse, set TRIS to 0 and write 1 to the PORT bit instead of setting TRIS to 1.

As I understand it, either of these will result in the line going high (is that correct?), but I'm not clear if one is somehow "better/safer" than the other.

Should I just follow the examples of the (presumably) more experienced implementations and write 1's to the PORT when the PIC is in control of the bus, or should I *always* make the line high by tri-stating to high impedance and letting the pullup do it?

I hope that makes sense and I haven't mixed any terminology - any general advice about best practices for open collector connections would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really wrong to set the pin HIGH, but doing so may cause **output contention**. That is, you may get into a situation where your code is driving the pin HIGH, but the device at the other end is trying to drive the same pin LOW. The PS/2 mouse (and keyboard) protocol uses open-collector signalling to avoid contention. In an open-collector system, signals are assumed to float HIGH when they are not driven by a pin, i.e. when the pin(s) are high impedance. A pin can safely be pulled LOW by the device at either end of the wire.

So, it's probably best to use TRIS in this case.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense. Does that mean if I drive a pin high and the mouse drives it low that I could blow a pin?

Comment: @RogerRowland Possibly, but it's unlikely if the short is brief. Still, better to avoid that situation.

Comment: Ok, I'll avoid it then. Sounds safer to me! One other point - would there be a significant difference in the time it takes the line to go high? Sorry if that's a stupid question. Still on a learning curve here.

Comment: @RogerRowland In principle, the line will go HIGH faster if you drive it HIGH. The pull-up resistor must charge the capacitance of the wiring. Driving it HIGH will supply a larger current and charge the capacitance faster. But the choice of pull-up resistor value, data rate and protocol should avoid any problems.

Comment: Thanks again John. My PS/2 mouse seems to provide ~12.5KHz clock, so I guess that's not "fast"? I've no idea what the built-in pullups are on my PIC though (I'm using PIC16F648A). I expect I'll suck it and see ....

Answer (score 2):

There is one case where it is useful to set the pin HIGH.

Where the open-collector logic is relatively slow, either because the pull-up resistor must be high (to save power) or because it's connected to a long wire or PCB trace, an output can be driven HIGH for one clock cycle and tri-stated in the next. (These must happen as an atomic operation, e.g. with interrupts disabled)

This gives a relatively fast rise time, and limits the duration of any contention to be short enough not to cause damage. (and of course that must be verified via the datasheets)

Comment: Ahh! The best of both worlds then? Fantastic! I'm running the PIC at 20MHz, so maybe only exposed for ~400ns if I do this in two consecutive instructions. I suppose a PS/2 mouse cable counts as *"a long wire"* so this would be a good approach?

Comment: You could do that, but it might be better just to add external pull-up resistors. Microcontroller pull-ups are very weak; they're mainly intended to keep undriven inputs from floating. You shouldn't need to drive the pin high for such a low speed signal. If it's really 12.5kHz, even the internal pull-ups are probably fast enough. You'd need an oscilloscope to be sure.